# "Cuddle", "snuggle" or "huggle"

Tags: differences, synonyms

There is a ton of words with similar, yet slightly different meaning that describe this kind of physical affection where we touch a loved one. What is the difference between *cuddle*, *snuggle* and *huggle*? What else is commonly used in this context?

Comment: None of your business how I touch my loved ones!

Comment: Then, there's also *nuggle*!

Comment: And of course, *fondle*!

Comment: You can also give affectionate *squeezes*! I'll give a full answer later!

Answer (score 3):

I've never heard "huggle" before...that may be a regional usage. I'd say cuddle and snuggle are roughly equivalent, though "snuggle" seems to me to have a connotation of places your faces together, in particular.

I would say that I cuddle my children.

Comment: *Huggle* is derived from *hug* + *cuddle/snuggle*. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huggle

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of *huggle* before, as well.
To my knowledge, *cuddle* and *snuggle* both mean a prolonged and affectionate hug, but *cuddle* can be used regardless of the person/people involved whereas *snuggle* is more passionate and intimate insofar as it's what you'd do with your significant other.

Comment: Unfortunately, snuggle can also be used without another person present, such as "snuggle under the covers", while cuddle (as far as I know) always implies the a person or the proxy of a person: "She cuddled her teddy bear".